# CGFloat is showing an error

Tags: objective-c, cgfloat

I have declared a CGFloat variable on my header file:

```
@property (nonatomic)CGFloat *heightOfSection;
```

Synthetized it on my implementation file, but it gives me an error trying to assign a value to it:

```
// Set height of section
            heightOfSection = 45.0f;
```

This is the error shown:

```
Assigning to 'CGFloat *' (aka 'float *') from incompatible type 'float'
```

Any idea to solve the issue?

Comment: Get rid of the asterisk. It's not an object type.

Comment: @rmaddy, I am giving you a lot of work today...Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind putting your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CGFloat` is a primitive type, not an object type. Your property should be declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat heightOfSection;
```